# Telerik Report Viewer export to PDF problems

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, pdf, export, telerik-reporting

I am using Telerik Reports in my site and when i see them from the browser everything is fine, but after exporting it to PDF the report comes separated in multiple pages, (the report in fact is just one page). Some text boxes will show in one page some in the other and the footer will show up in every page. I have checked the design, for differences between text boxes properties but have found nothing until now.
Any idea why such e a thing happens?
Thank you

Comment: Can you share your report or something that might help to see the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching trying almost everything i figured out that this can be solved by changing the margins at page setup of the report viewer preview. In some cases even lowering the font of the entire report page will work